# What are the polite and neutral versions of “cut the bull*’?

Tags: word-choice, politeness, idiom-requests, euphemisms, nonsubjective

I was wondering what are the polite and neutral versions of *cut the bullshit*?

Suppose one calls his mobile customer service for signal problem, but the representative endlessly tries to promote irrelevant products.

I seem to remember there is some word other than *bullshit* to be used with *cut*, which is more neutral, but I cannot recall it.

Comment: Some answers [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/21715/5822) _may_ help.

Comment: "Talk as you eat."

Comment: @kiamlaluno: What do you mean?

Comment: In Italian there's the proverb: *parla come mangi*, which means talk simply and directly (to the point) as you would if you were eating. Don't try to cover your speech with fancy meaningless words i.e. bullshit.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Cut to the chase.

Cut (or get or return) to the point (neutral if preceded by "let's" or "we should" instead of "you").

Comment: +1 Cut to the chase. I was just looking up the [link](http://idioms.yourdictionary.com/cut-to-the-chase). But "get to the point" is impatiently rude, and "cut the crap" is offensive. I'd take those out if I were you.

Comment: @Kit, agree on the last.  I've seen "cut to the point" be neutral when it's collaborative, as in "we should..." or "let's...".  Edited.

Comment: I see your point about "cut to the point."  You're right, if you say "let's cut to the point," that probably would not be interpreted as rude.

Answer (score 4):

> That's very interesting. Now, I was
>   hoping you could help me with [repeat
>   request].

Answer (score 4):

Cut to the chase...

Let's try to focus on "x"...

Let's get to the heart of the matter...

Coming back to the point...

We're off topic, let's refocus...

Let's not fool around...

...and the 'not so polite and not very neutral' version from my years as a craps supervisor in a casino, "Cut the f-ing bullshit already, because if you try to pile it any deeper we're all going to f-ing drown."

Answer (score 3):

A slightly more polite and a lot less vulgar phrase is, **let's get to it (the point).**

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to

> ***cut the crap***

Comment: Thanks! Nice one. Is it offensive? Hope it is not.

Comment: Cut the crap is pretty offensive.

Comment: I would actually consider "cut the crap" as somewhat **more** offensive/insulting than "cut the bullshit."  "Bullshit" (often shortened to **BS**) has become a relatively neutral term for the red tape/trivia/meaningless routine we all have to deal with every day, so "cut the BS" has a sense of "You and I are both adults; we can take all of that as read, and get down to business."  "Cut the crap", however, has more of a flavor of "You are lying to me or being intentionally obstructive" - it feels more personal, in other words.

Comment: It looks a bit more offensive to me as well... Natives here should show up! :D

Comment: Well. I did not put this thing up as the polite/neutral term. I was referring to the part of the question, where the author says - "I seem to remember there is some word ... But I cannot recall it."

Comment: And of course, it is obvious, Crap is as offensive, if not more, as is Bullshit.

Comment: Then it would have been better posted as a comment than an answer, I guess.

Comment: As a native AmE speaker, I find 'crap' much less offensive than 'shit'. It is still on the vulgar side of things, but it feels like it is towards the limit of what can be said on TV.

Comment: @Mitch - I also am a native USAite, and I agree: as a **word**, "crap" is less offensive than "shit."  But as a **concept**, "bullshit" (although it's obviously a _type_ of "shit") has come to be far less offensive than either.

Comment: *bullshit* is vulgar, *crap* is offensive, they're both **rude**. @MT_Head hits on the right idea, getting called out for *crap* is a personal accusation. getting called out for *bullshit* is about cutting away small talk or formalities or shared lies that get in the way of real discussion. but both are definitely disrupting social norms.

Answer (score 1):

Some useful expressions from American politics:

1. [**No malarkey**!](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2019/12/01/joe-biden-mocked-no-malarkey-campaign-pledge/)

“Malarkey” is an old-fashioned Irish-American slang word meaning “bull*” ([Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=malarkey)).
I wouldn't recommend actually using this one.

2. [**Straight talk**](https://www.military.com/daily-news/2018/08/27/trail-john-mccain-what-i-learned-straight-talk-express.html)

This is a common expression, and can be used as follows:

> Hey, straight talk, what’s your opinion about “x”?

---

Another expression that’s worth mentioning is:

3. [**Don’t beat around the bush**.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/beat-around-the-bush)

For example,

> Let’s not beat around the bush and address this issue directly.

Answer (score 0):

"Can we stay on point?"  "Can we stick to the matter at hand."

I had a professor who constantly would remind us to "Keep it terse, pithy and to the point."  He could easily have added "breviloquent" to that list of words.

(Of course the humor was that he was being wordy in saying that we should be brief.)

Answer (score -1):

From lexico: Let's get down to business.  [image]

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to post textual answers as images.